# Qualifier concept in ddd

Tags: domain-driven-design

According to Eric Evans, associations should

1. Impose a traversal direction
2. Add qualifiers and reduce multiplicity
3. Not be present if it is non-essential

I am not able to understand qualifier concept, how do we add to reduce multiplicity. Can any body explain with example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is general oop. read more [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1398623&seqNum=16) and [here](http://etutorials.org/Programming/UML/Chapter+6.+Class+Diagrams+Advanced+Concepts/Qualified+Associations)